# How to run Python at different time in everyday by reading a time list in excel

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks

I would like to run a file (.py) at different time in everyday.
The time will be defined in a excel file.
There are more than 1 time slot in a day.
Below are the example:

```
Reload Time
2017-12-27 21:45
2017-12-27 23:18
2017-12-28 00:23
2017-12-28 01:37
```

Thx!

Comment: The question is not really about Python but about job scheduling. Are you on Linux or on Windows? On Linux, you can use cron.

Comment: Please give more information on your configuration, as well as if this spreadsheet is on Google Sheets.

Comment: It is on Windows and not a server.

Comment: @Louis, did you check resources I shared in my answer? Did not they help?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you need to create a job that will read Excel everyday for that day's schedule times and create a job to run the target .py file for each time listed in the list

OK, to be more specific to read data from files, please check following resource
https://python101.pythonlibrary.org/chapter8_file_io.html

Then to interact with Windows to create scheduled tasks, please refer to
https://ziade.org/2007/11/01/scheduling-tasks-in-windows-with-pywin32/

I hope that is helpful

Comment: Hi Eralper, 

Where should i create the job that will read Excel everyday?

Comment: Don't you work on Windows, so your job should be scheduled on Windows

Answer (score -1):

you can make a list by the excel file and run batch with python and parameters

Comment: In case you didn't notice, that's exactly what the OP did. Their question is, _how_?